# Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'IEnumerator'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I'm really, really new to Unity.

I've followed a tutorial for a script to Google maps to a raw image. But I'm getting an error and have no idea how to solve it.

Can anyone help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GoogleAPI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url;

    public RawImage img;

    public float lon;
    public float lat;

    public int zoom = 14;
    public int mapWidth = 600;
    public int mapHeight = 620;

    LocationInfo li;

    public enum mapType { roadMap, satelite, hybrid, terrain };
    public mapType MapSelected;

    public int scale;

    IEnumerator Map()
    {
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api       /staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap \n" +
                " & markers = color:blue % 7Clabel: S % 7C40.702147,-74.015794 & markers = color:green % 7Clabel: G % 7C40.711614,-74.012318 \n" +
                " & markers = color:red % 7Clabel: C % 7C40.718217,-73.998284 & key =  AIzaSyDh1_nS-l7nWOFWvt0Gg9-9dY_11qWzK_Q ";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        img.texture = www.texture;
        img.SetNativeSize();
    }


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        img = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
        StartCoroutine(Map);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

The error is at StartCoroutine (Map);

The (Map). I'm getting "Argument 1: cannot vert 'method group' to 'IEnumerator'"

On the video the dude did that and it just worked and all the comment seem to be people who found success in that method. I have not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing parantheses: `StartCoroutine (Map());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This passes the method / method group, not the results of the method:

```
 StartCoroutine(Map);
```

This executes the method and returns the result, passing it to your Coroutine method:

```
 StartCoroutine(Map());
```

Whenever you're given a casting or conversion error about a method group, look for where you've forgotten your parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to start a coroutine.

One is directly passing the routine as a parameter

```
 StartCoroutine(Map());
```

Or using the string name of the method but this version has a higher runtime overhead to start the coroutine.

```
 StartCoroutine("Map");
```